# How to use NATIVE BLE DFU library for IONIC 2?

Tags: android, ios, ionic2

I am creating BLE app using IONIC 2 .I need to use DFU OTA library to support firmware-update for users. Nordic provided great examples and source code.

dfu lib for iOS : https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-DFU-Library

full project(iOS) : https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-nRF-Toolbox

dfu lib for Android : https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library

Problem is how to implement same for IONIC app? Is there any plugin available for same? Or any way to implement firmware update OTA in IONIC 2 ?

---

**Update Question**:
I have found this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nordic-dfu . Can anyone explain how to use this in application as I am able to add it in my ionic app but the guide on how to import and use methods is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there aren't any open source plugins available. You will need to create a cordova plugin to wrap the ios and android SDKs.

Here's how you can get started writing the plugin:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

You would then add your plugin to your ionic app like: 
ionic plugin add ~/path/to/your/awesome/nordicdfu/plugin

You may find Don Coleman's excellent BLE plugin helpful: https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

Answer (score 0):

This for iOS .
 1) - Add the iOSDFULibarary into the project.
          pod 'iOSDFULibrary' (using pod)
 2) - import libarary `import iOSDFULibrary`.

3) - declare the following constants.

```
  static var legacyDfuServiceUUID  = CBUUID(string: "00001530-1212-EFDE-1523-785FEABCD123")
  static var secureDfuServiceUUID  = CBUUID(string: "FE59")
  static var deviceInfoServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: "180A")
```

4) - Scan the bluetooth device with specific services. Then device will goes into DFU mode.

```
 func startDiscovery() {
       if !scanningStarted {
           scanningStarted = true
           print("Start discovery")
           // By default the scanner shows only devices advertising with one of those Service UUIDs:
           centralManager!.delegate = self
           centralManager!.scanForPeripherals(
               withServices: [
                   ImpulseUpdateFirmwareVC.legacyDfuServiceUUID,
                   ImpulseUpdateFirmwareVC.secureDfuServiceUUID,
                   ImpulseUpdateFirmwareVC.deviceInfoServiceUUID
                   /*, customServiceUUID*/],
               options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
       }
   }

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

    switch central.state {
    case .unsupported:
        print("BLe Unsupported")
        break
    case .unauthorized:
        print("BLe unauthorized")
        break
    case .poweredOff:
        let alertMessgesInst = AlertMessages.sharedInstance
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertMessgesInst.actofit_Title, message: alertMessgesInst.trun_On_blueTooth, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: Constants.General.OK, style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
        break
    case .poweredOn:
        startDiscovery()
        break
    case .unknown:
        print("BLe unknown")
        break
    default:
        break
    }
```

}

5 - Into "didDiscover peripheral" delegate method of the 'CBCentralManager' , call the DFU library into the .

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    let name = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as! String?

    // Ignore dupliactes.
    // They will not be reported in a single scan, as we scan without CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey flag,
    // but after returning from DFU view another scan will be started.
    centralManager.stopScan()
   let selectedFirmware = DFUFirmware(urlToZipFile: zipFilePathULR!, type: .application)
           let initiator = DFUServiceInitiator().with(firmware: selectedFirmware!)
           initiator.logger = self // - to get log info
           initiator.delegate = self // - to be informed about current state and errors
           initiator.progressDelegate = self // - to show progress bar
           // initiator.peripheralSelector = ... // the default selector is used

           let controller = initiator.start(target: peripheral)


}
```

This will update firmware of RNF52 chipset device.